# bounding an integral by the function's derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Say $f\in C^1$ and has compact support in [-1, 1]. Furthermore,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f'(x)\rvert dx \le 1$$
I want to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(x+y)-f(x) \rvert dx \le |y|$$

First I tried using the mean value theorem, then I tried the fundamental theorem of calculus. Either I made a mistake somewhere, or neither is the right approach. Seems like this should be simple, so just a hint is enough.

Comment: Write $f(x + y) - f(x) = \int_x^{x + y} f'$ and change the order of integration.

Comment: @T.Bongers nice! but how do you take care of the absolute value? i've never seen how to do a change of variables in $\int \left| \int \cdots \right|$...

Comment: Bring it inside the integral.

Comment: Maybe I do need more than a hint. When I try that, I get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+y)-f(x)|dx \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_x^{x+y} |f'(s)|ds dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{s-y}^s |f'(s)|dx ds$. Did I switch it incorrectly?

Comment: @Kurt: So keep going. (Note you're assuming $y>0$ here.) That final integral is just $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y|f'(s)|ds = y$.

Comment: Oh wow of course. How did I miss that. Thanks! Quick note: should be $\le y$ in your comment.

Comment: Oops. Of course. Too late to edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: If the support is contained in $[-1,1] $ then why are you integrating beyond those limits?

Comment: Also, it would be nice to have hypotheses on $f.$

Comment: The compact support made another part of the problem easier. I don't think it mattered here. As for hypotheses on $f$, $f \in C^1$. I don't think we used the continuity of the derivative though.

Comment: @T.Bongers why use FTC? $f$ is not necessarily absolutely continuous.

Comment: @zhw. yes the derivative needs to exist at every point or $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @Kurt we dont need continuity of the derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the summarize comments, which basically contained an answer. First assume that $y\ge 0$. The proof where $y<0$ is very similar. Since $f'$ is continuous, we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$f(x+y) - f(x) = \int_x^{x+y}f'(s)ds$$
Thus
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+y)-f(x)|dx &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left| \int_x^{x+y}f'(s)ds \right| dx\\
&\le \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_x^{x+y}\lvert f'(s)\rvert ds dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{s-y}^s \lvert f'(s)|dx ds\\
&= y\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f'(s)| ds\\
&\le y
\end{align}
$$

When $y<0$, we use the same argument, but get $\ge y$ at the end. Thus we have the result
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+y)-f(x)|dx \le |y|$$

Comment: I'm guessing you voted down the answer. Was that really necessary? Feel free to contribute to it or give suggestions. As for Fubini's, $f'$ is continuous and has compact support, so we wouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x+y)-f(x)|dx \le 2+ |y|$ $\quad$ If $f'$ exists at every point and not necessarily continuous.

Proof:
If $f'$ exists at every point
Then according to Lemma 6.14  from 'The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy , Perron , and Henstock (Graduate Studies in Mathematics Volume 4 )' by Russell A. Gordon:$\quad$$|f(x+y)-f(x)| \le \int_{x}^{x+|y|} |f'(t)|dt$

$|f(x+y)-f(x)| \le \int_{x}^{x+|y|} |f'(t)|dt\le\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f'(t)|dt\le1$

$B=$ $[-1 -y, 1-y]$ $\bigcup$ $[-1 , 1]$

$|f(x+y)-f(x)|$ $\le 1$$\quad$for $x \in B$

$|f(x+y)-f(x)|$ $=0$ $\quad$for $x \notin B$

$\mu^*(B) < 2+|y|$

we conclude $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x+y)-f(x)|dx \le 2+ |y|$